# "<function funcname at address>" printed instead of function's result

Tags: python

I'm new at python and I'm trying to create this game using words picked at random based on words picked
from a previous function and whenever I run the script it keeps spitting out this weird code that I have no idea what it is. What I want instead of spitting out this weird code I want it to be a word. Do you have any tips of how to make it happen?

```
from random import randint
import time

from line import bloodline

bloodline()
if bloodline == 'Shadow':
    spower = randint(1,6)
    if spower == 1:
        infinity = 'shade'
    elif spower == 2:
        infinity = 'decay'
    elif spower == 3:
        infinity == 'black'
    elif spower == 4:
        infinity = 'vampiric'
    elif spower == 5:
        infinity = 'eclispe'
    print (infinity)
elif bloodline == 'Verglas':
    ipower = randint(1,6)
    if ipower == 1:
        infinity = 'frozen'
    elif ipower == 2:
        infinity = 'artic'
    elif ipower == 3:
        inifinity ='glacier'
    elif ipower == 4:
        infinity = 'white'
    elif ipower == 5:
        infinity = 'biting'
    print (infinity)
elif bloodline == 'Flame':
    fpower = randint(1,6)
    if fpower == 1:
        infinity = 'blazing'
    elif fpower == 2:
        infinity = 'searing'
    elif fpower == 3:
        infinity = 'burning'
    elif fpower == 4:
        infinity = 'sparking'
    elif fpower == 5:
        infinity = 'scorching'

    print (infinity)
```

output:

```
<function bloodline at 0x043D1E88>#this right here is what i'm trying to get rid off
```

code from line file:

```
from random import randint

def bloodline():
    bloodline = randint(1,101)
    if bloodline >= 61:
        bloodline = 'Verglas'
    elif bloodline >= 20:
        bloodline = 'Flame'
    elif bloodline >= 0:
        bloodline = 'Shadow'

print (bloodline)
```

Comment: when you print bloodline try putting parenthesis after it like this `print(bloodline())`

Comment: You are printing `bloodline` which is a function

Comment: What do you want the output to be, if anything? what do you want the `bloodline` function to do?

Comment: Couple of things to change: (1) return a value from bloodline() instead of printing it, (2) binding that to a value, say bl, (3) don't use "bloodline" as a variable name inside of the function "bloodline()"

Comment: I guess you really need basic understanding of programming languages and must read the python docs. I am not sure of your understanding but I can see you don't fully understand how functions. You should work on learning and understanding programming languages how they work rather than learning to code directly. Baby steps are important.

Answer (score 1):

`bloodline` is a function, not a variable containing the value that it returns. You need to assign the function call to a variable, then use that in the rest of the code.

```
from random import randint
import time

from line import bloodline

bl = bloodline()
if bl == 'Shadow':
    spower = randint(1,6)
    if spower == 1:
        infinity = 'shade'
    elif spower == 2:
        infinity = 'decay'
    elif spower == 3:
        infinity == 'black'
    elif spower == 4:
        infinity = 'vampiric'
    elif spower == 5:
        infinity = 'eclispe'
    print (infinity)
elif bl == 'Verglas':
    ipower = randint(1,6)
    if ipower == 1:
        infinity = 'frozen'
    elif ipower == 2:
        infinity = 'artic'
    elif ipower == 3:
        inifinity ='glacier'
    elif ipower == 4:
        infinity = 'white'
    elif ipower == 5:
        infinity = 'biting'
    print (infinity)
elif bl == 'Flame':
    fpower = randint(1,6)
    if fpower == 1:
        infinity = 'blazing'
    elif fpower == 2:
        infinity = 'searing'
    elif fpower == 3:
        infinity = 'burning'
    elif fpower == 4:
        infinity = 'sparking'
    elif fpower == 5:
        infinity = 'scorching'

    print (infinity)
```

And in the `line` file, you need to return a value from the function.

```
from random import randint

def bloodline():
    result = randint(1,101)
    if result >= 61:
        result = 'Verglas'
    elif result >= 20:
        result = 'Flame'
    elif result >= 0:
        result = 'Shadow'
    
    return result
```

Don't use the same name `bloodline` for the function name and a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The last line, `print (bloodline)`, is printing out the function itself, not it's return value, since you're not calling it.  However, if you were to call it and print it out, it would print out `None`, since the function `bloodline` doesn't return anything.

The simplest way to fix this is to remove `print (bloodline)` altogether, or `return`ing the value you want to use.

Another thing I noticed is that the variable `bloodline` could be interpreted by Python to be the function itself, so it may rebind the function to a value.

Comment: it would print `None` since the `bloodline` function doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

Within the bloodline() function you should add a `return(bloodline)` at the end, as well as removing the `print(bloodline)` after defining the function.

Answer (score 0):

You should also add `return` statement at the end of the function definition